# Make pop-up ads open in a new tab while the user stays on the same page

Tags: popup

This is code pop-up ads that I use now. When you click anywhere on the page, an advertisement opens on a new page and the visitor moves to the advertisement page.

```
<script type='text/javascript' async='async' src='//b.m2track.co/adb/zone/114.js?v=1.22'></script>
```

I want when I click anywhere on the page, the advertisement opens, but the visitor remains on the same page and does not go to the page of the advertisement that opened in a new tab

Comment: I believe this is a browser setting, whether new tabs open in the background or the foreground.

Comment: Also pop-up ads are annoying. Most browsers will block them automatically.